# How to install these modules and packages offline on Linux?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, installation

How do I install all the modules and packages listed below offline on Linux?

```py
import time 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: Are you asking, for example, how you would install the selenium package without an internet connection?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb`. Replace package_name.deb with the actual name of the package you downloaded.

Comment: 1) `apt-get install` requires an internet connection 2) the question was about Python packages, specifically the `selenium` package.